# How @JoinColumn and @MappedBy works

Tags: java, hibernate, foreign-keys, entity-relationship

I am confused over working on @JoinColumn and @MappedBy.

Consider following example
Here is my Department class with unidirectional relationship

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "DEPARTMENT")
public class Department {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "DEPARTMENT_ID")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer departmentId;
    @Column(name = "DEPARTMENT_NAME")
    private String departmentName;
    @Column(name = "LOCATION")
    private String location;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "DEPARTMENT_ID")
    private List<Employee> employees = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

I have  a `list of employees` in `Department class` over which I have specified `@JoinColumn` so it will add `department_id` FK in `employee table`.

but with bidirectional relationship I will define the classes like

```
Department.java
@Entity
@Table(name = "DEPARTMENT")
public class Department {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "DEPARTMENT_ID")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer departmentId;
    @Column(name = "DEPARTMENT_NAME")
    private String departmentName;
    @Column(name = "LOCATION")
    private String location;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "department")
    private List<Employee> employees = new ArrayList<>();
}

Employee.java
@Entity
@Table(name = "EMPLOYEE")
public class Employee {
    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "emp_seq", sequenceName = "seq_employee")
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "emp_seq")
    @Column(name = "EMPLOYEE_ID")
    private Integer employeeId;
    @Column(name = "EMPLOYEE_NAME")
    private String employeeName;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "DEPARTMENT_ID")
    private Department department;
}
```

but with bidirectional relationship why do I need to place `@JoinColumn` over `department` in `Employee class` and write @`MappedBy` over `list of employees` in `Department class`?

## update

so how does @MappedBy and @JoinColumn works?

Comment: why 2nd `Department ` mapping does not have `@Table` and `@Entity` annotations?

Comment: I forgot to copy it. Thanks @JordiCastilla for noticing it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Actually, seems you're not using `@MappedBy` annotation but `mappedBy = "department"` in `@OneToMany`.

In simple words, mappedBy tells to `hibernate` that key of relationship is on the other table (class in this case).

Think on this: *usually when you link 2 tables in any DB System, just 1 of those has the foreign key constraint to the other one right?*

**What `MappedBy` allows you to link from the table not containing the constraint to the other table.**

About `@JoinColumn` it's easier, here you have in table foreign key, so you tell hibernate this is not only a column, but a column that must **join** a table.

> The join column is declared with the `@JoinColumn` annotation which looks like the `@Column` annotation. It has one more parameters named *referencedColumnName*. This parameter declares the column in the targeted entity that will be used to the join. Note that when using *referencedColumnName* to a non primary key column, the associated class has to be Serializable. Also note that the *referencedColumnName* to a non primary key column has to be mapped to a property having a single column (other cases might not work).

Find [HERE](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/annotations/reference/en/html/entity.html) `hibernate` mapping documentations.